# Remove <script> tags from a string along with the content between them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked and looked and looked but I couldn't find anything on this.  So lets say I have this string...

```
var str = '<script>blah blah blah</script><a>...</a><div>...</div><p>...</p>';
```

I need to strip out the script tags out of the string along with all the content between the tags.  Once the script tag is stripped I need to append it to a textarea.  How in the world do I do this with jQuery?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

since nobody else is going to post a simple and reliably-working routine, i guess i will:

```
function noscript(strCode){
   var html = $(strCode.bold()); 
   html.find('script').remove();
 return html.html();
}


alert(   noscript("<script>blah blah blah</script><div>blah blah blah</div>")    );
//shows: "<div>blah blah blah</div>"
```

Comment: Worked like a champ!  I also had to do this in another area of the code for another text area so the function was a good call!  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var str= "<script>blah blah blah</script><div>blah blah blah</div>";
var html = $(str.bold()); 
html.find('script').remove();
```

Comment: var html = $(str.bold()); works better since it doesn't rely on having an outside wrapper tag...

Comment: I get [object Object] when I do the following...

var str = data
var html = $(str);
html.find('script').remove();
alert(html);

Comment: please note that you use can html.html() to get the "sanitized" string back.

Comment: Just saw that after I made the comment.  I updated my question as well.  Forgot something in there.

Comment: @dandavis when I do this.  var str = data
   var html = $(str);
   html.find('script').remove();
   $('#codeWindow').text(html.html());  It puts the content of the script tag in the textarea.  Which is oppsit of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi str is the full string with the script tag included.

Comment: `find` will actually find nothing - the script is at the "current" level and not a descendant of any element

Comment: For appending it to the text area you can simply write this:- document.getElementById("textarea1").value = html.find('script').remove();

Comment: @user1115040:- I guess it was mentioed that you can use return html.html();. Anyways if that worked for you then thats great. P.S. Do try to give upvotes for answer which helped you ;)

Comment: Yea for some reason html.html() was giving me the text inside the <script> in the context that I used it before.

Comment: @barrettathome:- Not an issue. My hard luck. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
var div = $('<div>').html(str);

div.find('script').remove();

str = div.html();
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/IabsE

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/skoley/9dnmbj3d/ ) of the answers which works best taken from several other sources, credit goes to them.

```
function noscript(strCode){
   var html = $(strCode.italics()); 
   html.find('script').remove();
 return html.html();
}

function noscript_alt(str)
{
var div = $('<div>').html(str);
div.find('script').remove();
str = div.html();
return str;}
```